# How to get property info from Powershell object?

Tags: powershell, object, definition

I have this object in Powershell which I obtained from a query against the SSRS Web Service:

```
$ds|gm


TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3tServer_ReportService2010_asmx.DataSource

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------

Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                    
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
Item        Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3tServer_ReportService2010_asmx.DataSourceDe...
Name        Property   string Name {get;set;}
```

If I list the $ds object:

```
$ds|fl

Name : AHPUsersData
Item : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3tServer_ReportService2010_asmx.DataSourceReference
```

What I need is the value of "Item" which actually appears to be the type of an object stored in "Item". I've try assigning $ds.Item to a new object but it just turns into a Powershell custom object and all that info goes away. I've tried various combinations of GetType with no success. Ultimately what I need is the last part of:

Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3tServer_ReportService2010_asmx.DataSourceReference

Which is the "DataSourceReference" string. This part can have two values, "DataSourceReference" or "DataSourceDefinition" and I need to test that to determine the code to execute next.

Relative newbie to Powershell and this one is a bit obtuse for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does `$ds | select -expand Item` return?

Comment: Perfect!!! Want to post as an Answer so I can flag it?

Comment: Sure. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand the `Item` with `Select-Object`:

```
$ds | select -expand Item
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you need, but you could also create your own custom `PSCustomObject` like this:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Name                = $ds.Name
    DataSourceReference = $ds.Item.DataSourceReference
    SomethingElse       = $ds.Item | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DataSourceReference
}
```

At first you select the `PropertyName` and then the `PropertyValue`, which can be anything you like. Hopefully this helps you out.